# One-way-function based on Friedberg numberings

Tags: complexity-theory, formal-languages, one-way-functions

A one-way-function is an easy to compute function $y=f(x)$ which is hard to invert. In 2000 [Levin](https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0012023) showed an example of a function which is one-way if there are one-way functions. As far as I know, it is still not clear whether true one way-functions exist.

Now with Friedberg numbering, which roughly speaking, is a programming language with the following properties:

- turing completeness
- no two programs perform the same task
- every computable function has a corresponding program but [there's no way to find it.](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/116708/89800) There is a non-existance proof of a compiler in this language. i.e. one can not programm with friedberg numberings. However, if you have for some reason a program in this language it is executable.

In the following argument has to be a a pretty basic flaw as it would establish the existance of one-way-functions if it would be right.

Suppose we have a regular programm $x_p$ in a "normal" language which computes $y = P(x_p)$. Here $P$ is the function which which maps $x_p \rightarrow y$.  Also assume a programm $x_F$ in the language of Friedberg enumberings which for some reason computes $F(x_F) = y$ too. If we invert the friedberg enumberings $F^{-1}(y) = x_F$ we have established a compiler for Friedberg numberings by inverting $F$, as we have established a mapping $x_P \rightarrow x_F$. However, we know there is no such compiler, hence our assumption $F$ is invertible is wrong. This establishes them as one-way-function as Friedberg numbering are perfectly computable, but not invertable.

**Possible loopholes**:

- It is clear that $F^{-1}$ needs to run forever for any input $y$, as every bijective function has an inverse. However, not every bijective function has necessarily a *computable* inverse. There might be a mapping, but we can not compute it in finite time. I'm not sure if this changes the argument. The point is if we can invert $F^{-1}$ than we have a compiler, and if we can't than we have a one-way-function. Also $F^{-1}$ might be approximateable.
- $P$ is not necessary halting for all $x_p$. Ok, lets restrict us to all halting $x_p$ (which is impossible to know beforhand)

If this argument would be right it would make Friedberg numbering a bijective one-way-function with the stronger guarantee of beeing impossible to invert instead of just beeing hard to invert.

What is wrong with this argument?

Comment: I still don't understand.  You're using $x_p$ for both the program and the input to the program.  That's pretty confusing.  Can you avoid using the same variable for two different purposes, please?

Comment: What's $F$?  Is $F$ the same as $P$?  Why are they two different variables if they are intended to represent the same mapping?

Comment: I suggest you explain more clearly how you will construct the compiler.  The ability to find $F^{-1}$ for a single $F$ does not imply that you have an effective algorithm to do this for all programs.

Comment: There ist no input to the program (lets make the input the empty string) It's just the programm. $F$ and $P$ are the respective engines which execute programs in their languages and deliver $y$.

Comment: But you wrote notation that shows an input, where you wrote $y=P(x_p)$.  I can't understand what you are getting at, so I'm afraid I can't help with this.  Sorry!  Hopefully someone else will be able to help you out.