# Are there infinitely many distinct implementations of any algorithm using any Turing-complete computational model?

Tags: computation-models, turing-completeness, church-turing-thesis

Subject pretty much says it all. My strong impression is that for any algorithm  and any choice of programming language or computational model, if it's Turing-complete, then there must be infinitely many ways to implement the algorithm such that a fixed interpreter for the language will necessarily return the same output, even if this is essentially just a matter of adding NOOP equivalents to the code.

Is this provably true, false, or unknown? And if applicable, can someone point me towards relevant keywords, in particular if this is an established theorem or conjecture?

Comment: I think this might be a duplicate of [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/116704/language-to-define-perfectly-a-programming-problem).

Answer (score 0):

No sooner did I click okay on my question than a plausible answer occurred to me. Posting to make sure this makes sense.

Since any TC language must be able to simulate any other TC languages, it requires only translating any given program through a simulation in another language and back again to get a much less efficient but equivalent program. Since you could do this arbitrarily many times, or with arbitrarily many languages in whatever order, that should work as a proof sketch.

Comment: This depends on exactly what "Turing-complete" means - see [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/116704/language-to-define-perfectly-a-programming-problem/116708#116708).

Comment: I was familiar with this concept, but not the name (Friedberg numberings). Yes, for my purposes, I'm discounting non-computable "magic" mappings like that which place unrealizable constraints on the translator algorithm, etc.

Comment: A Friedberg numbering *is* computable, though, and the existence proof is completely constructive - you could actually whip up a "Friedberg language" and use it. It's not that Friedberg numberings are noncomputable, but rather that they have too *little* content (they don't satisfy the relevant universality property).

Comment: @NoahSchweber I must be misreading that post badly... "the map [...] is not computable. Essentially, what this means is that programming in the usual sense is impossible in the context of a Friedberg numbering: while every computable function has a corresponding program, there's no way to find it." And either way, my post here was motivated by a practical scenario, so unless Friedberg can be effectively applied in real life, it's interesting but immaterial here.

Comment: The Friedberg numbering is computable, but the *translation into it* isn't. We can actually make and use a Friedberg numbering; what we can't do is make a Friedberg numbering *and then* answer questions of the form "Where is program $P$ in this numbering?" in a computable way.

Comment: Here's a precise statement: there is a computable partial *binary* function $f(x,y)$ such that for every computable partial *unary* function $s(x)$ there is exactly one $n$ such that $$s\simeq\lambda x.f(x,n).$$ This $f$ is basically a Friedberg numbering.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Okay, that's what I thought, and what I was trying to articulate in my first reply. Still, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Just add nonsense operations that don't affect the result at will.

Comment: This might not be something you can actually do, depending on how precisely we define "Turing-complete" - see [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/116704/language-to-define-perfectly-a-programming-problem/116708#116708).