# Is the set of all halting programs for all universal Turing machines recursively enumerable?

Tags: turing-machines, turing-completeness

I understand that one can use dovetailing to recursively enumerate the domain of a UTM.

However, I am trying to recursively enumerate the domain of all possible UTM.

My starting point was to use a similar algorithm to dovetailing, but then I realize that I do not know the set of all universal Turing machines.

Proving that an arbitrary two-input Turing machine is a UTM : UTM(TM, d) for all TM and all d; one has to try it out for all possible inputs and confirm that it does, right? And this is non-decidable.

So I can't recursively enumerate all halting programs for all universal Turing machines. I must first pick a specific program known to be a UTM before I can do it? Is my argument sound?

edit: I suppose the question reduces to; given an arbitrary language or Turing machine, prove that it is Turing complete or a universal Turing machine, or is the question undecidable?

I suspect that it is undecidable.

Comment: Hi, can you please properly define (in mathematical formula) the language you want to prove this for?

Comment: @nirshahar Well, I am trying to hit a general result, so if I specify a language, I break the generality. But we can do it as follows: Assume a finite alphabet Z. The words of this alphabet are W. Then a one-input TM is a function of W to W, and a two-input DM is a function of W x W to W. Finally, an encoder function <.> is a map from TM to W. Then if DM(<TM>,w>)=TM(w) for all words, then DM is a UTM. With this I can dovetail the words and enumerate the domain of a UTM. But since I can't know if a given word w = <DM> is or isn't a UTM, I can't dovetail the words over only UTMs.

Comment: FYI, a TM is *not* a function from words to words. TMs can get stuck in an infinite loop and not output anything. Or maybe output an infinitely long string

Comment: And even more confusing is that some of the infinite strings it can output, but some others no TM can ever output.

Comment: @nirshahar Well it has to be a function from a set to another set... what are the those sets? I suppose technically TM is a function from words to Dom(TM); the later also a set of (carefully chosen) words?

Comment: @Anon21 A machine is more complicated than just a function, and even if you simply want to talk about the functions computed by Turing machines (which is often a good idea) you need to be thinking in terms of **partial** functions. Incidentally, see [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/116704/language-to-define-perfectly-a-programming-problem/116708#116708) or [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361862/what-are-some-examples-of-theorem-requiring-highly-subtle-hypothesis/361870#361870) for some subtleties around how we might precisely define the notion of a UTM or similar object.